# listing subclasses in jena with koala.owl ( Person and Student example)

Tags: subclass, jena, ontology, class-hierarchy

when I visualize the well known koala.owl ontology I see in the hierarchy the class **Student** as subclass of **Person** and **MaleStudentWith3Daughters** is a subclass of **Student**. I wrote a code which extract a hierarchy of a given class, i.e. when I choose the class all its superclasses and subclasses are stored in a separated model. It works with other classes but it seems having a problem with **Student**, **Person** and **MaleStudentWith3Daughters**.

Here is the code:

```
    //here is the code which determines all superclasses of a given class c
    //adding a class and its superclasses to new model
        public void ajouterHierarchieSupAuModel(OntClass c){
            ArrayList listesuperdirect = new ArrayList();

            OntClass sup;

            //adding super classes

                    listesuperdirect = lamere.getSuperClasseDirecte(c);
                    if(listesuperdirect!=null){
                    for(int i=0;i<listesuperdirect.size();i++)
                    {
                    sup = (OntClass) listesuperdirect.get(i);
                    OntClass supp = module.createClass(sup.toString());
                    OntClass classmodule= module.createClass(c.toString());
                    classmodule.addSuperClass(supp);

                    }

                    for( int j=0;j<listesuperdirect.size();j++){ 
                    c=(OntClass) listesuperdirect.get(j);
                    ajouterHierarchieSupAuModel(c);//recursive call
                    }
                    }
        }

 // the same thing for subclasses of a given class c
```

When I experimented it through classes as **Marsupials** or **Forest** it works very well but It seems that **Person** and **Student** are not belonging to the same hierarchy ***although they appear belonging to the same hierarchy in Protégé***.

Any answer will be welcome ! Thanks.

Comment: Well, I can't say for certain how to code this, however the reason you're having trouble with `Person` and `Student` is that the heirarchy is inferred. If you look at the actual .owl file, you will see that Student is not defined as `owl:subClassOf Person`. Rather `Student` is defined as a class that is equivalent to `Person` having properties `hasHabitat some University` and `isHardWorking value true`

Comment: Thank you Kunal, I see the problem, but In the class hierarchy of Protégé it is shown that Person is a superclass of student. How can I do this with jena (how can I extract Student as subclass of person). In fact, I am a little bit confused here, If Student is not defined as subclass of Person, why it is shown as a subclass in Protégé? If effectively Student is not a subclass of Person, Is it  means that Person have no any subclass?

Answer (score 0):

I am compiling my comments into an answer because there is a lot of information there and it is becoming unwieldy to limit myself to 500 characters.

The reason you're having trouble with `Person` and `Student` is that the heirarchy is inferred. If you look at the actual .owl file, you will see that Student is not defined as `owl:subClassOf Person`. Rather `Student` is defined as a class that is equivalent to `Person` having property restrictions `hasHabitat some University` and `isHardWorking value true`

A property restriction is a special kind of class description. It describes an anonymous class, namely a class of all individuals that satisfy the restriction.
Look [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#Restriction) for more information on property restrictions

To ease your confusion a bit, think of owl classes as a sets and subclasses as subsets. In this particular case we have defined the class (set) of `Student` as the intersection of the class(set) `Person` and the classes(sets) given by the two mentioned property restrictions. We have not explicitly stated that `Student` is a subclass(subset) of `Person`, however since `Student` is a more restricted version of `Person`, it is inferred to be a subclass(subset).

The main difference being the explicit use of the `rdfs:subClassOf` or `owl:subClassOf` tag. If you look at the file, both Marsupials and Forest, both have the `rdfs:subClassOf` tag. However `Student` does not, however since it is a restricted version of a `Person` it is inferred to be a subclass of Person. Look [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/#Classes.2C_Properties.2C_and_Individuals_.E2.80.93_And_Basic_Modeling_With_Them) for more information.

Look through Jena's ontology API [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/) or the Javadoc [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/) for more Jena code specific information.

A Suggestion from my side is try running a reasoner on this ontology in Jena before you try to use your code to get subclasses, it might work out better. For steps on how to do that go [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#reasonerAPI)